# A pie chart in chart.js with data from json

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js, pie-chart

I'm drawing a pie chart using data from a database. 
My database is very simple, but it has a different structure than all examples which I was checking. So it looks like this:

```
id | food | tickets
1  | 300  | 50
```

I guess the id column is unnecessary because it won't be more records.

**data.php**

```
 <?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once "../polaczenie.php";

//get connection
$mysqli = @new mysqli($host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id,food, tickets FROM arch_kategorie ORDER BY id");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

When I'm checking results by localhost://data.php I have this:
[{"food":"300","tickets":"50"}]

And now the problematic part:

**app.php**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "data.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);

            var food= [];
            var tickets= [];

            for(var i in data) {
                food.push(data[i].food);
                tickets.push(data[i].tickets);
            }

            var ctx1 = $("#chartcanvas-1");

            var data = {
                labels : ["food", "tickets"],
                datasets : [{
                    label : "Result",
                    data : food, tickets
                    backgroundColor : [
                        "#DEB887",
                        "#A9A9A9"
                    ],
                    borderColor : [
                        "#CDA776",
                        "#989898"
                    ],
                    borderWidth : [1, 1]
                }]
            };

            var options = {
                title : {
                    display : true,
                    position : "top",
                    text : "Pie Chart",
                    fontSize : 18,
                    fontColor : "#111"
                },
                legend : {
                    display : true,
                    position : "bottom"
                }
            };

            var chart1 = new Chart( ctx1, {
                type : "pie",
                data : data,
                options : options
            });
        });
    },
    error : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And of course html:

**index.html**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #chart-container {
        width: 80%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>

<div class="chart-container">
    <div class="chart-container">
        <canvas id="chartcanvas-1"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The question is how to change var data to make it works

Comment: Shouldn't this line of your **js** `data : food, tickets` be like this `data : [food, tickets],`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have a second definition of variable `data` in your Ajax success function. Function arguments (parameters) work as local variables inside functions, that is the same way as they were defined with the keyword `let` inside the function.

Second, `data` in `datasets` require to be a `number[]` and your values that you get in JSON are strings.

Third, one thing is unclear to me, since describing your data set you wrote that:

> I guess the id column is unnecessary because it won't be more records.

but then you process the `data` inside of the Ajax success function as it was a multi element array of objects, i.e. using a `for` loop.
So it depends on you'd want to achieve with what type of data.
A trivial solution with a single row from your SQL table the Ajax success function would look like:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var ctx1 = $("#chartcanvas-1");
  
  var chartData = {
    labels : ["food", "tickets"],
    datasets : [{
      label : "Result",
      data : [Number(data[0].food), Number(data[0].tickets)],
      backgroundColor : [
        "#DEB887",
        "#A9A9A9"
      ],
      borderColor : [
        "#CDA776",
        "#989898"
      ],
      borderWidth : [1, 1]
    }]
  };
  
  var options = {
    title : {
      display : true,
      position : "top",
      text : "Pie Chart",
      fontSize : 18,
      fontColor : "#111"
    },
    legend : {
      display : true,
      position : "bottom"
    }
  };
  
  var chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type : "pie",
    data : chartData,
    options : options
  });
}
```

With multiple rows taken from your SQL table you could use each array object (i.e. your SQL row including the `id` field used as a `label`) as a separate dataset. Since the `datasets` is a JSON array of objects you could transform your initial `data` as follows:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);

  var ctx1 = $("#chartcanvas-1");

  var datasets = data.map(row => {
    let set = {
      label: row.id,
      data: [Number(row.food), Number(row.tickets)],
      backgroundColor: [
        "#DEB887",
        "#A9A9A9"
      ],
      borderColor: [
        "#CDA776",
        "#989898"
      ],
      borderWidth: [1, 1]
    };
    return set;
  });
  console.log(datasets);
  
  var chartData = {
    labels : ["food", "tickets"],
    datasets : datasets
  };
  
  var options = {
    title : {
      display : true,
      position : "top",
      text : "Pie Chart",
      fontSize : 18,
      fontColor : "#111"
    },
    legend : {
      display : true,
      position : "bottom"
    }
  };
  
  var chart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
    type : "pie",
    data : chartData,
    options : options
  });
}
```